# AWS Snapshot vs AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

While we can create an AMI from every snapshot, then shall we go for AMI? Or just keep creating snapshot and whenever we need just create image from particular snapshot and use it? I am a bit confuse about the usage of both them at the same time. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is not very clear. Could you please Edit your question and provide more details about what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried and what difficulties you have encountered? That way, you will be more likely to receive a suitable answer. (Your answer did not help explain your question, either.)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE!

Sorry, I got it, actually I can but snapshot does not contain instance configuration! I can make an image and build an instance from it but it wont have my instance configuration in time I made snapshot!

So I might create one image when I finish with setup my instance, and then start to take snapshot, then If I don't make any change in instance settings, no need to update my image. Whenever I need new instance with same data, first I will create an instance from that image and make a volume from snapshot and attache it to new instance.

Please correct me If I am wrong!

Comment: You create an image out of an instance and a snapshot out of a volume. You can later create an instance directly from your AMI or a volume from your snapshot.